# Maps detail request returns country instead of formatted address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using a reference like the one below, a `getDetails` request from the Google Maps API returns only the country name as a `formatted_address` instead of the correct address. This only happens for some references. Oddly enough the `lat` `lon` geometry info is still accurate.

For example: `CkQ6AAAAD2g0J8ZLITG7f4r0o5wrWjM9V-6AFj4Ow3Ho_Y42sJM-H-4jZ2WTdLNEjPDGSHT7OLHddGrrGJZeZ_5iwV2fKBIQ9TcBmVdYKoNQcJU5uyNm3xoUO36bjZCWDwTVY6Hs6GIA2EruYa8`should return *Merianplatz, Frankfurt am Main* and not *Germany*

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places-API returns results for places created by users, when the users did not provide the desired details, you will not get them.  (On [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=12076958130838851004)  you will also get only the address "Germany")

However, you may additionally geocode the location based on the returned geometry`(50.1201960, 8.695603999999999)`, what will give you the correct address: `Merianplatz, 60316 Frankfurt am Main, Germany`